# why cant i find the control txt in this vb.net asp:repeater no matter what i do on rgroups itembound

Tags: css, vb.net, asprepeater

i cant find the control txt which is a textbox in the repeater i have used the following on rgroups itemdatabound event

------------itemdatabound code

```
Protected Sub rGroups_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rGroups.ItemDataBound


Dim dv As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
If dv IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim rptOrderDetails As Repeater = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rSubgroups"), Repeater)
   Dim control1 As Control = rGroups.Items(0).FindControl("txt")
  Dim txtbox As TextBox = DirectCast(control1, TextBox)

    If rptOrderDetails IsNot Nothing Then

      Dim dv_co As New DataView(dssubmenu)

    dv_co.RowFilter = "groupId = '" + txtbox.Text + "'"
      rptOrderDetails.DataSource = dv_co

      rptOrderDetails.DataBind()
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

------------repeater code

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rGroups"  Runat="server">  
 <HeaderTemplate>

  <ul id="prod_nav" class="clearfix">  

   </HeaderTemplate>   
<ItemTemplate>        
<asp:TextBox ID="txt"  Text="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"groupid")%>" runat="server">     </asp:TextBox> 

<li class="top"><a href="05-Pink-02-Category-List.html" class="top_link">   <span class="down"> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"groupname")%></span></a>   
 <asp:Repeater ID="rSubgroups"  Runat="server">          
 <HeaderTemplate>              

<ul class="sub">          

    <li class="clearfix">    
                    <ul>       
 </HeaderTemplate>            <ItemTemplate> 

         <li><a href="partviewer.aspx?subgrp=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"subgroupId")%>">  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"subgroupname")%></a></li>  
      </ItemTemplate>        
  <FooterTemplate>                    </ul>                  </li>                </ul>            <        </FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to get the `txt` control for the databound *item* in the `Repeater`, not from the `Repeater` control itself. The eventargs argument for the [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event contains the newly created [`RepeaterItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.aspx). It is from that item you want to retrieve your control:

```
Dim control1 As Control = e.Item.FindControl("txt")
```

Comment: treied that but got 

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Line 670:       Dim control1 As Control = rGroups.Items(0).FindControl("txt")
Line 671:      Dim txtbox As TextBox = DirectCast(control1, TextBox)

Comment: @David: then the repeater has not yet been databound, or the source data is empty. In what context are you trying to get access to the control?

Comment: have a look at my answer above could not include all the code in the comments